# how to compare or relate 2 getJson?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to compare these two Json's and get get1 to return all the data except the ones that the idConcepto and impuesto are the same as get2

example:

> get1 =
>   https://maxtechglobal.com/vencimientos/agip/ib.php?cuit=30712413871

```
"data": [
{
"impuesto": "IVA",
"idConcepto": "30",
"id": "266",
"datos": {
"anticipo": "PRESENTACION",
"vencimiento": "2017-09-18",
"agencia": "AFIP",
"id_perfil": "146"
}
},
{
"impuesto": "GANANCIAS SOCIEDADES",
"idConcepto": "10",
"id": "268",
"datos": {
"anticipo": "PAGO",
"vencimiento": "2017-09-13",
"agencia": "AFIP",
"id_perfil": "146"
}
}
]
```

> get2 =
>   http://estudiomiramonte.com/app/api/impuestos_modal.php?id_perfil=146

```
 "data": [
{
"impuesto": "IVA",
"idConcepto": "30",
"id": "607",
"datos": {
"anticipo": "PRESENTACION",
"vencimiento": "2017-09-18",
"agencia": "AFIP",
"id_perfil": "187"
}
}
]
```

> Result i need:

```
"impuesto": "GANANCIAS SOCIEDADES",
"idConcepto": "10",
"id": "268",
"datos": {
"anticipo": "PAGO",
"vencimiento": "2017-09-13",
"agencia": "AFIP",
"id_perfil": "146"
```

```js
//get1

$.getJSON("https://maxtechglobal.com/vencimientos/agip/ib.php?cuit=" + "cuit", function(result) {
  for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
    if (result.data[i].id != otheresult.data[i].id) {
      var table_abril = document.getElementById("AGIP_edit_todos");
      var row = table_abril.insertRow(-1);

      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

      cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i].id;
      cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].impuesto;
      cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes">';
    }
  }
});
```

```js
//get2

$.getJSON("api/impuestos_modal.php?id_perfil=" + id + "", function(result) {});
```

Comment: You need to do one of the `$.getJSON` in the callback function of the other, or use promises to wait for both to complete.

Comment: and how do I make the condition so that it only shows the ones that do not repeat themselves?

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.filter()` to remove elements that are duplicated.

Comment: You can also use a library like lodash or underscore.js for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array#filter` and `array#some` to get the data which don't share same `idConcepto` and `impuesto`.

```js
var get1 = {"data": [{"impuesto": "IVA","idConcepto": "30","id": "266","datos": {"anticipo": "PRESENTACION","vencimiento": "2017-09-18","agencia": "AFIP","id_perfil": "146"}},{"impuesto": "GANANCIAS SOCIEDADES","idConcepto": "10","id": "268","datos": {"anticipo": "PAGO","vencimiento": "2017-09-13","agencia": "AFIP","id_perfil": "146"}}]},
    get2 = { "data": [{"impuesto": "IVA","idConcepto": "30","id": "607","datos": {"anticipo": "PRESENTACION","vencimiento": "2017-09-18","agencia": "AFIP","id_perfil": "187"}}] };

var result = get1.data.filter(function(o1){
  return !get2.data.some(function(o2){
    return o1.impuesto === o2.impuesto && o1.idConcepto === o2.idConcepto;
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

Since, both of your data are being fetched from external source, you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Once you have both the result you can use the above function.

**Live Example**

```js
var get1 = $.getJSON("https://maxtechglobal.com/vencimientos/agip/ib.php?cuit=" + "30712413871").done();
var get2 = $.getJSON("https://estudiomiramonte.com/app/api/impuestos_modal.php?id_perfil=" + "146").done();

Promise.all([get1, get2]).then(function([obj1, obj2]){
var result = obj1.data.filter(function(o1) {
  return !obj2.data.some(function(o2) {
    return o1.impuesto === o2.impuesto && o1.id === o2.idConcepto;
  });
});

console.log(result);
})
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: but how to replace the getJson in get 1 and get2?

Comment: Updated the solution, Please check.

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: following your code use it for different functions, however it seems very repetitive, is there any way to optimize this? https://jsfiddle.net/nxkuek1L/15/

Comment: You should make a common function and pass promise1, promise 2 and the id of the table to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the data from getJson async with promises in ES6 or jQuery.
Once you have both getJSONs in such vars you can do it by lodash.remove() and Array.some() like this:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var data1 = [...JSON1];

var data2 = [...JSON2];

_.remove(data1,  obj1 => data2.some(obj2 =>
    ((obj1.impuesto === obj2.impuesto) &&
        (obj1.idConcepto === obj2.idConcepto))));
```

If you neither work with ES6 nor promises you can go this way:

```
var data = {};

$.getJSON("https://maxtechglobal.com/vencimientos/agip/ib.php?cuit=" + "30712413871", function(obj) {
    this.data.data1 = obj;
    clearData(this.data);
}.bind({data:data}));

$.getJSON("api/impuestos_modal.php?id_perfil=" + "146", function(obj) {
    this.data.data2 = obj;
    clearData(this.data);
}.bind({data:data}));

function clearData(data) {

    var data1 = data.data1;
    var data2 = data.data2;

    if (data1 && data2) {
        _.remove(data1,  function(obj1) { data2.some(function (obj2) {
            return ((obj1.impuesto === obj2.impuesto) &&
                (obj1.idConcepto === obj2.idConcepto))})});
        console.log(data1); // Your solution
    }

}
```

Comment: i like the answer but return me this: `Uncaught Error: Module name "lodash" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])`

Comment: i use this cdn: ´<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js" and <script src="js/require.js"></script>

Comment: if you import by CDN, like you do, you can just remove that line: var _ = require('lodash');

Comment: Your script in jsfiddle doesn't work because you are not working with ES6 and you are not dealing with the async data so I have updated the solution above to adapt to your use case :)

Comment: what I meant when I said it did not work is that the console returns the complete array of data1 without removing the repeated ones, As for the new code you wrote, I get the same result...